# No veo el menú de un módulo que estoy desarrollando

Tags: odoo

Estoy empezando con la versión 12 de Odoo, al hacer el ejemplo que propone su página oficial: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html#build-an-odoo-module  no veo las opciones de menú "Course". 
En el log me sale este error:

```
WARNING masanz odoo.modules.loading: The model openacademy.course has no 
access rules, consider adding one. E.g. access_openacademy_course,access_openacademy_course,model_openacademy_course,base.group_user,1,0,0,0
```

He leído algo de un administrador nuevo en esta versión, permisos... ¿alguien me puede ayudar? 
Gracias

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. Si, es cuestión de permisos. Hay que dar permisos al modelo que quiero mostrar. En mi caso el modelo es `openacademy.course`. He añadido la línea siguiente al archivo `ir.model.access.csv`:  `access_openacademy_course,openacademy.course,model_openacademy_course,,1,1,1,1`.

Comment: Saludos Merche Oroz, en la parte inferior de esta página encuentras "Tu Respuesta" seguido de un campo amplio para colocar la respuesta, utilízalo y marca la respuesta como aceptada para colaborar con la buena salud del sitio :D

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado. Sí, es cuestión de permisos. Pero hay dos soluciones:

- Hay que dar permisos al modelo que quiero mostrar. En mi caso el modelo es `openacademy.course`. He añadido la línea siguiente al archivo ir.model.access.csv: `access_openacademy_course,openacademy.course,model_openacademy_course,,1,1,1,1.` .
- Han cambiado los derechos de acceso predeterminados del Administrador. Si creas un nuevo módulo sin declarar explícitamente qué usuario puede acceder al módulo, por defecto dicho módulo no será visible ni por un administrador.
  En versiones anteriores a Odoo12, el usuario **admin** era un usuario especial y pasaba los controles de seguridad. En la versión 12 esto ha cambiado, y **admin** pertenece a todos los grupos de seguridad, pero es un usuario normal. Odoo12 dispone de un **superusuario** que pasa los controles de acceso de seguridad.
  **Cuando logueamos como un usuario administrador, activamos el modo desarrollador y pinchar en Become Superuser.**
  En la parte superior derecha, donde aparece el usuario logueado aparecerá que indica que está logueado el Superusuario, el cual no tiene ninguna restricción de acceso. De este modo, sí que podremos ver las opciones de menú que se han creado.